# How to overload [] operator in c++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I defined a class V_class which has the following private fields:
int* array;
int size;

Let define V_class var;

I want to overload [] operator in order to access the element var.array[index] when I write  var[index]. I managed to do this, but I must do another thing: My method should work also when I want to write var[index] = a_number.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing in?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the interface of classes like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)?

Comment: I dont know how to do var[index] = a_number

Comment: I am not allowed to use std::vector

Comment: @pkenobi23 You're allowed to look at the prototypes of `vector`'s overloads for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return the object by reference, the assignment would work. See how `std::vector` or another standard container does it.

Also, be sure to provide both `const` and non-`const` versions of your operator.